Screen Stuck on "Shared Conference Waiting..." in ConnectyCube Video Conferencing Demo App
Question:
I'm experiencing an issue with the ConnectyCube video conferencing demo app. When I start a video call, the screen gets stuck on the "Shared Conference Waiting..." message and I am unable to disconnect the call. Here are the details of my setup:
Platform: Flutter
ConnectyCube SDK Version: connectycube_flutter_call_kit: ^2.5.0,connectycube_sdk: ^2.11.3
Steps to Reproduce:
Launch the ConnectyCube video conferencing demo app.
Initiate a video call.
The screen displays "Shared Conference Waiting..." indefinitely.
Attempting to disconnect the call does not work.
What I've Tried:
Restarting the app and the device.
Checking the internet connection.

Yesterday they had some issues on the Calls server. Now it should work well.
